Absorption and emission spectrum terminology
Hi everyone recently i was looking for laser crystals and since I am an autodidact i was confused by the terminology and units of the optics domain. And specialy by the absorption and emission spectrum sometimes the emission is expressed by (a.u) in tousnds and sometime from 0.0 to 1.0 i guess this is a percent am not sure. Second is the absorption wich use absorption coeficient $Cm^{-1}$!!



So what is the difference between the two emissions unit?
How to read the absorpion unit? And is it better to have a high value or a low value for better absorption for the pumped incident?
(I am not a native so bear with me please thank you).

Please format equations using mathjax as this is nigh unreadable.

Just as a side comment, a.u. means "arbitrary units", which doesn't have to be a percentage. It can be anything.

@MattHanson what equation?

@GabrielYbarraMarcaida "It can be anything" this doesnt look promising .

The units are “equations” for this purpose.

Strictly speaking, a.u. is the abbreviation for "astronomical units" being measured in terms of the distance between the sun and the earth. The abbreviation for "arbitrary units" is arb. units.
